# How-to paste text into the Cloud9 editor?

Tags: android, cloud9-ide

I want to copy a URL (or any text) and paste that into Cloud9.  Doesn't work. In other words, if I have some text in my tablet's clipboard, I can't paste it into the Cloud9 editor.

(I can paste URLs into this editor just fine.)

From what I can tell, you can only cut-paste text that originated inside the Cloud9 editor. So far I've tried Opera and Google Chrome for Android. Going to try Firefox next...

Comment: I assume this will be fixed eventually, at which point this message will self-destruct.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Firefox 44.0.1 This worked for me.

1. Go to `about:config`
2. Search for `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled`
3. Double-click it to change the value to `true`

Now you can copy and paste freely from within or from outside of the cloud9 editor. No boundaries. It's amazing!

Comment: I have aleady `true` value. Not works for me. I have Mozilla Firefox 91.0

Answer (score 5):

I'm having similar trouble with Cloud 9's IDE too; also on a Mac. One solution I found was to highlight the code you want to copy/paste and drag it onto the code editor. The code I wanted was on [this](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#top) page in one of the examples. A standard Cmd+C didn't work, nor did selecting 'copy' from a right click - the drag & drop is all I have found that works.

Answer (score 3):

http://lifehacker.com/enable-copy-paste-in-web-pages-that-disallow-it-with-a-1601848114

1. Go to `about:config` in Firefox
2. Search for `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled`
3. Double-click it to change the value to `false`

Restart your browser and you're done!

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this works in some browsers and not in others, and appears to have to do with how the browser implements clipboard handling.

Having recently purchased a tablet in an effort to move all of my work to remote machines (C9) I tried a few different browsers for copy/paste capability

```
+ Chrome
+ Firefox
x Opera
x UC Browser
x Puffin
x Dolphin
```

Chrome and Firefox are the only two browsers that offer copy/paste into a C9 environment.

This is unfortunate since they are also the most verbose when it comes to screen usage. Most other browsers allocate more screen realestate to content and offer better support of interactivity.

Tested on Android 5.

Answer (score 0):

I can paste into Cloud9 using Android Firefox Beta.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the support that Cloud9 has for tablets but there is limited clipboard functionality when copying and pasting on Mac with a right-click and this could be similar behavior. It will popup something telling you how it's limited specifically. Using Ctrl/Cmd + C to copy has no limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with Google Chrome. Solution:

Go to Settings -> Privacy and security -> Site Settings -> .console.aws.amazon.com -> clipboard > allow

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Editors -> Code Editor (Ace) -> Check the Copy with Empty Selection

Answer (score -1):

paste it in notepad / textedit and copy again from the texteditor and it will fine to paste in cloud9

Answer (score -2):

I can't paste either (beagelbgone black, windows 7, firefox). And no, it's not a buffer limit, I can't paste either a single character, neither in c or js files. Methink is a bug of the new ide (the one with dark colors). Switching to the old bbb image (with the light-colored cloud9 i/f) works well. Ended up looking for the folders and copying my files there from debian (putty, "find / -name yourfile", copy the new source code over, for bbb the cloud9 is in /var/lib).